# Three.js tubeGeometry not coloring properly

Tags: three.js

I have a code that lets users enter data and plots it with a tube geometry. The code seems to work fine most of the time, however, one of the test data sets is not coloring properly.

[Here is an example page for a site that I am building that solves for the position and velocity of a bungee jumper.](http://www.cadwolf.com/Documents/Documentation/Examples/The_bungee_jumper_problem) Scroll to the bottom of the page and you will see a three js environment with a sin wave and a plot of the position of the jumper. These two items are charted with separate color maps and you can see that the sin wave is colored properly but the data is not.

At first I thought that maybe the data was too sparsely populated, but that was not the problem.

The code for this is too long to really paste here, but the fact that it charts right for all other data sets makes me think that I am missing something inherent to the tubeGeometry function.

Any ideas as to why the one tube is miscolored?

UPDATE: When I add additional interpolated points between each existing point in the data set, the error lessons. The more the padding, the less the error. This leads me to think that the error is due to the difference between the interpolation of the spline function from Three.SplineCurve3 and the true data. This would also explain why my other examples work fine since they are all sinusoid data.

How can I prevent SplineCurve3 from doing this, or what else can I use to create the Tube geometry?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the mesh length counting problem (three did not count length on vector+vector+vector but by mesh.position+bounding radius)
Maybe you can separate curve to parts and color each part independent on their lenght.

There are some working approaches:

- https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Curve.html
- https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Surface.html
- https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Graphulus-Function.html

Comment: I am following those functions, specifically the graphulus curve. However, I think that the spline portion is adding points and I don't want that. Any ideas on how to prevent interpolation of the spline function or how to read the data from the extracted points?